# How can I expose an Office file using Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, ms-office

I'd like to expose Office (Excel, Word) files from a web site.
I understand Office 14 now provides Silverlight components to view/edit Office files.
What do I need to setup on my web site to use these components?

Answer (score 1):

One option that will also work with office 2007 is to save your files as XPS (XML Paper Specification) using this free [Microsoft add in](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en) (it may be built into office 14?).

You can then use the silverlight controls to create a an XPS viewer (there are many [examples online](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2007/05/22/lighting-up-the-xml-paper-specification-proof-of-concept-xps-reader-for-silverlight.aspx)).

Comment: This is interesting but I understand the file would be read only.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it's too early to say how Office 14 will work on the web unless you are a betatester. From the info that I've seen, Microsoft will be using Silverlight (or fallback to javascript, ajax and html) for the online version but nowhere does it say anyone else will be able to use Microsoft's Silverlight components on their own website.

Comment: I have Office 14 beta. I don't know where to look for the Silverligt support.

Comment: From what I've read it doesn't use SilverLight. The writers of that article were surprised.

Comment: According to this site it will use Silverlight when available:
http://on10.net/blogs/sarahintampa/Microsoft-Office-Web-Applications-Your-Burning-Questions-Answered/